# Remove jdt dependencies from XTEXT 2.0 project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, xtext

how can i remove JDT deperndencies from an XTEXT 2.0 project?
I tried to follow the hints [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336217) (comment 11) but i didn't success in removing JDT dependencies.

When I try to validate the product Eclipse says that the plugin org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.ui is missing, but if i add that plugin, new dependecies to jdt core and ui are created.

Thanks

Comment: I know nothing... but comments 22-23, same reference, didn't help?

Comment: Unfortunately they do not help. I didn't create any wizards from XTEXT and this part in my code is all commented. I also tryed to comment it out and put the flag pluginProject = false, but it didn't help.

Comment: It may be necessary to remove the common.types.ui dependency from your UI project manually. If you don't use the Java types integration, you can ignore this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i asked about was related to the creation of a new xtext plugin where i pasted a grammar previously developed. I didn't success in removing the dependecies from that project.

Instead i imported the old plugin in Indigo with Xtext 2.0 and then I fixed the various errors related to different implementations of the new framework. In this case the project, which didn't belong to JDT, does not create any dependency errors.